# Returning right type in Scala function

Tags: scala

I have following code to handle response from rest call. I am trying to convert various HTTP code from server to custom exceptions so that it can be handled by the caller.

```
def handleResponse(eventualResponse: Future[WSResponse]): Future[WSResponse] = eventualResponse.map { response =>
  response.status match {
    case x if x >= 200 && x <= 204 => response
    case x if x==403 => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case x if x >= 500 => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case _ => Future.failed(new NoRetryException(s"Non-Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
  }
}
```

But I am getting compile error as:

```
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]
required: play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is `.. => response` in the first case - all the branches must return the unifiable type, but the first returns a WSResponse and there is no type-relation between a WSRespones and a Future. This is exactly what the error message is saying. Using `.. => eventualResponse` would result in a Future (compatible with the other case branches); although maybe it would be better / is intended to ditch the Future here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within `Future#map`, you're running a function in case the future completed successfully and are not expected to return a new future (unless you *want* a `Future[Future[...]]`.
You can either throw these exceptions instead

```
def handleResponse(eventualResponse: Future[WSResponse]): Future[WSResponse] = eventualResponse.map { response =>
  response.status match {
    case x if x >= 200 && x <= 204 => response
    case 403 => throw new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}")
    case x if x >= 500 => throw new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}")
    case _ => throw new NoRetryException(s"Non-Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}")
  }
}
```

or use `flatMap`

```
def handleResponse(eventualResponse: Future[WSResponse]): Future[WSResponse] = eventualResponse.flatMap { response =>
  response.status match {
    case x if x >= 200 && x <= 204 => Future.successful(response)
    case x if x==403 => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case x if x >= 500 => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case _ => Future.failed(new NoRetryException(s"Non-Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to actually `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
def handleResponse(eventualResponse: Future[WSResponse]): Future[WSResponse] = eventualResponse.flatMap { response =>
  response.status match {
    case x if x >= 200 && x <= 204 => Future.successful(response)
    case x if x==403               => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case x if x >= 500             => Future.failed(new RetryExternalException(s"Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
    case _                         => Future.failed(new NoRetryException(s"Non-Retryable Exception ${response.status} - ${response.body}"))
  }
}
```